# React Flux - can not dispatch in the middle of a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have a dropdown with lists. When a list is clicked, it is displayed in a table on the other side of the page.

Whenever a new list is created, I want to display it just as if it was clicked(as shown in the code below). However, in order to display it in the table, I need to call `ListAssignmentsStoreActions.loadListAssignments(list);`.

```
handleClick: function() {
    var list = this.props.data;
    ListAssignmentsStoreActions.loadListAssignments(list);
},

//invoked after initial rendering
componentDidMount: function() {
    var loadAssignmentsForList = this.props.loadAssignmentsForList;
    console.log("Name " + this.props.data.name);
    if(loadAssignmentsForList){
        this.handleClick();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get:

```
 error = Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch. at invariant
```

I don't know how to display the list other than by calling an action.

Comment: Hard to tell without the code. It's a dispatch bug, we may need your action file for example...

Answer (score 4):

I believe you got Flux wrong.

When you select a list in the dropdown you dispatch an Action, say `ListSelectedAction` which has a property holding the list id.

You should have a Store, say `ListStore` which registers a listener/callback on the dispatcher, listening for `ListSelectedAction`. ListStore updates one of its property, say `currentList` with list id contained in `ListSelectedAction` and emits an Event, say `LIST_CHANGED`

The Table component listens for `LIST_CHANGED` events (not actions) and when receiving it, reads from the `ListStore` the `currentList` id. (`ListStore` is passed as a prop to Table)

In summary,
Dropdown -> `ListSelectedAction` -> `ListStore` -> `LIST_CHANGED` -> Table

Same deal with the New Button

New Button -> `NewListAction` -> `ListStore` -> `List_CHANGED` -> Table